# Binding temporary to r-value reference produces error

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a pImpl without using a unique_ptr. I don't understand while writing something like this:

```
class PublicClass
{
public:
    // Some stuff
    PublicClass();
private:
    class ImplClass;
    ImplClass&& mImpl;
};

class PublicClass::ImplClass
{
public:
    ImplClass() {}
};

PublicClass::PublicClass() : mImpl(ImplClass()){}
```

produces following compilation error

```
Reference member 'mImpl' binds to a temporary object whose lifetime would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object
```

while writing the following

```
PublicClass::PublicClass() : mImpl(std::move(ImplClass())){}
```

is ok. R-value references should not extend life-time of temporaries, as in first snippet?

Comment: Lifetime extension happens in local scope. The second case is not ok either because you end up with dangling reference.

Comment: `std::move` returns an rvalue reference, that *could* be ok (if it isn't moving a temporary). Your compiler just doesn't understand the full problem. Some, like clang, *does* warn that moving a temporary is no good in general.

Comment: "without using a `unique_ptr`". Obviously `unique_ptr` was added to the standard library because it fulfilled a need. It appears as if you expect `ImplClass&&` to fulfil the role of `std::unique_ptr<ImplClass>`. But if it was that simple, then what need would there be for `std::unique_ptr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [class.temporary](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.temporary):

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference **except**:

> - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor's ctor-initializer ([class.base.init]) persists until the constructor exits.

This is applicable to both of your examples. That is, in both of your given cases you have a **dangling reference.** Its just that in case 2 of your example the compiler is not able to give us the appropriate error/warning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must understand that every object requires the storage. You have 3 storages:

- Stack
- Heap
- Static storage (the place where global variables are defined)

Both `PublicClass` and `PublicClass::ImplClass` are classes and to create an instance of this class you need the storage.

So you first decide where do you want to allocate the `ImplClass`.

In case if you want to be able allocate both `PublicClass` and `PublicClass::ImplClass` on the stack, compiler must know the size of the `ImplClass` at **compile time**. I mean you cannot allocate the object on the stack if the size of the object is not known at compile time at the point where object is created. What you can do is to pre-allocate the memory using `char[N]` variable

```cpp
class PublicClass
{
  // must be large enough to fit the ImplClass
  static constexpr auto PublicClassImplSize = 128; 

  // The storage for ClassImpl
  char alignas(void*) impl_[PublicClassImplSize];

  class ImplClass;

public:
  PublicClass();
  ~PublicClass();
};

// cpp
#include <new>

class PublicClass::ImplClass
{
    char buf1[10];
//    char buf2[10000];
};

PublicClass::PublicClass()
{
  static_assert(sizeof(ImplClass) <= PublicClassImplSize);
  new (impl_) ImplClass();

}

PublicClass::~PublicClass()
{
  reinterpret_cast<ImplClass*>(impl_)->~ImplClass();
}


int main()
{
    PublicClass o;
}
```

In case if you do not care where `ImplClass` is allocated, you can allocate it on the heap. In this case you use `new/delete` operators to allocate/release the memory and implement RAII inside the `PublicClass` to manage the resource.

`unique_ptr` is an example of the RAII-class. If for any reason you do not want to use it, you must implement the RAII inside the `PublicClass`. I.e. you implement constructor which allocates the `ClassImpl` on the heap and you implement the destructor, which releases the resources. You also have to care about move/copy constructors and move/assignment operators, as default behaviour provided by C++ language does not work right here.

```cpp
class PublicClass
{
  class ImplClass;
  ImplClass* impl_{nullptr};

public:
  PublicClass();
  ~PublicClass();

  PublicClass(PublicClass&&) noexcept;
  PublicClass& operator=(PublicClass&&) noexcept;
};

// cpp
#include <new>
#include <memory>

class PublicClass::ImplClass
{
    char buf1[10];
//    char buf2[10000];
};

PublicClass::PublicClass()
{
  auto impl = std::make_unique<ImplClass>();

  // ... more initialization

  // Initialization is completed
  impl_ = impl.release();
}

PublicClass::PublicClass(PublicClass&& obj) noexcept
  : impl_(std::exchange(obj.impl_, nullptr))
{
}

PublicClass& PublicClass::operator=(PublicClass&& obj) noexcept
{
  delete impl_;
  impl_ = std::exchange(obj.impl_, nullptr);

  return *this;
}

PublicClass::~PublicClass()
{
  delete impl_;
}


int main()
{
    PublicClass o;
}
```

In case if by design you have only one instance of the object, you can allocate the `ClassImpl` in the global namespace. Personally, I do not like this solution.

##### Update

> I mean you cannot allocate the object on the stack if the size of the object is not known at compile time at the point where object is created

The use of `alloca` function is out of scope :)

Comment: "Global namespace" - no, that's a place where names live, not where objects live. You're missing "static storage duration" in that list. Objects defined in _any_ namespace scope have static storage duration.

Comment: "In case if you want to be able allocate ImplClass on the stack, compiler must know the size of the ImplClass at compile time." - True, but misleading. That applies for **any** allocation,

Comment: "you use new and delete operators and you need a RAII-class to manage the resource.". That should be "or", not "and".

Comment: @MSalters Re "That applies for any allocation". In case if you allocate object in the heap, the size of the allocated memory does not have to be known at compile time. I.e. if you use `malloc` function to allocate the memory block, the `size` argument is a runtime value.

Comment: @MSalters On "That should be "or", not "and"". What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you use `new/delete` **OR** you use a RAII class. E.g. `std::vector` does the `new[]/delete[]` for you. And we prefer RAII since `delete` is so easy to forget.

Comment: @MSalters,  What I meant is that in case if `unique_ptr` cannot be used, the topic starter should use `new/delete` operators to allocate/release the resource **and** implement RAII pattern to ensure allocated resources are released.

Comment: The question is tagged C++11, so `unique_ptr` can be used. In C++98 there was `auto_ptr`, but that should not be taught anymore now that we have better solutions.